# Check if a folder of .txt files contains words from Listbox

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

Im trying to make a program that encrypts or hashes a list of words in md5. So far I can do that easily enough, now Im trying to figure out how to check 8 .txt to see if they contain the hashed string which is stored in a listbox. If not add the hash and word (Hash:Word).

```
     Public Function Md5FromString(ByVal Source As String) As String
    Static local_MD5 As MD5 = MD5.Create
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each b As Byte In local_MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Source))
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"))
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

After generating 10K or so I wanna check the .txts to see if they contain any matches. If no match found, add them. Also I have each .txt sorted as follows:
Hash_Pass1.text stores hashes beginning with a 0 or 1.
Hash_Pass2.txt stores hashes beginning with a 2 or 3
etc.
The path to the 8 .txt

\HP\Hash_Pass1.txt

\HP\Hash_Pass2.txt

I imagine some sort of FOR loop would work here just not sure where to start.
Would regex work here better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your question is just for checking all your files so there is some way to start.

```
Dim listOfMd5 As New List(Of String) ' Your MD5 list
For Each md5 In listOfMd5
    Dim fileName = "\HP\Hash_Pass" & GetFileNumberFromMd5(md5) & ".txt" ' Function to get the correct file to check according to what you want
    Using reader As New StreamReader(fileName)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains(md5) Then ' md5 found
                ' Found : do stuff
                Continue For
            End If
            ' Not found : do stuff
        End While
    End Using
Next
```

About regex I'm not sure this will be more efficient than that.
Hope this helps.